# C++ Function pointer incorrect types

Tags: c++, pointers, types, arguments, lpstr

I need to use the following function but I'm in trouble with the args:

In this case the IP Address is not setting.

```
cwbCO_SysHandle system;
LPSTR ipAddress = "";
ULONG ipLength = 32;
cwbCO_GetIPAddress(system, ipAddress, &ipLength);
```

I know I need to pass a pointer to the LPSTR as an argument but setting the following code didn't work either:

```
cwbCO_SysHandle system;
LPSTR ipAddress = "";
ULONG ipLength = 32;
cwbCO_GetIPAddress(system, &ipAddress, &ipLength); //Incompatible types LPSTR* and LPSTR
```

What's the correct way?

***Syntax***

UINT CWB_ENTRY cwbCO_GetIPAddress(cwbCO_SysHandle system, LPSTR IPAddress, PULONG length );

***Parameters***

cwbCO_SysHandle system - input

```
Handle that previously was returned by cwbCO_CreateSystem or cwbCO_CreateSystemLike. It is the
IBM i identification.
```

LPSTR IPAddress - output

```
Pointer to a buffer that will contain the NULL-terminated IP address in dotted-decimal notation (in
the form "nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn" where each "nnn" is in the range of from 0 to 255).
```

PULONG length - input/output

```
Pointer to the length of the IPAddress buffer. If the buffer is too small to hold the output, including
room for the terminating NULL, the size of the buffer
```

Comment: Remove the ampersand, most likely LPSTR is already a typedef that is a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found documentation, [cwbCO_GetIPAddress](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaik/rzaikcwbcogetipaddress.htm)

The relevant part here is (emphasis added):

> LPSTR IPAddress - output
>   Pointer to a **buffer** that will contain the NULL-terminated IP address in dotted-decimal notation (in the form "nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn" where each "nnn" is in the range of from 0 to 255).

So your code should look more like this:

```
cwbCO_SysHandle system;
char ipAddress[32]; //A buffer, not a pointer!
ULONG ipLength = 32;
cwbCO_GetIPAddress(system, ipAddress, &ipLength);
```

Also, make sure you do initialize your `system` with `cwbCO_CreateSystem` or `cwbCO_CreateSystemLike`.

Comment: I'm getting strange characters in the char buffer. How can I make the `char` buffer legible? I mean, convert it to string. I tried string str = string(ipAddress); But the string is empty. I also tried `stringstream` but it keeps showing strange chars.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid did you initialize your `system`? Did you check the return value from `cwbCO_GetIPAddress`?

Comment: Okay, The cwbCO_SysHandle was wrong. cwbCO_CreateSystem function sets a cwbCO_SysHandle pointer and I was using the pointer handler. I needed to use the handler used to create the system. Thanks.